# Bugmenot (registration bypasser) alternative that doesn’t suck?

Tags: webapp-rec, privacy

I used to love [Bugmenot](http://www.bugmenot.com/)...but then they started blocking more and more sites. Now I'd say a good 75% of the time I try to find logins on bugmenot, the site is blocked. Is there a service like bugmenot that doesn't block sites?

For example, all of these sites require registration to download files posted by users, and all of them are blocked from BugMeNot. dcemu.co.uk, ubuntuforums.org, club.cdfreaks.com

To be clear, this problem is because BugMeNot stops users from adding logins for them, not because of the individual sites themselves are blocking logins from bugmenot.

I know of things like mailinator, but the whole point of BugMeNot is so I don't have to go through the hassle of registering and setting up an account with fake details just to download that one useful piece of information from a site I never plan to visit again.

Comment: I'd love an alternative to Bugmenot... I used to use it all the time to get away from all the abolutely pointless registrations that every site now seemingly requires.  These days it's near useless with lots of "Upvote to see pw" rubbish.

Comment: Ever tried mailinator http://www.mailinator.com/faq.jsp ?  Fill out the form with an email address like `davr1205@mailinator.com`.  Mailinator will create that email account automatically when the first email is sent to it.  Just remember that all email accounts are accessible to the general public.  I wouldn't use it if the service has a habit of sending passwords via email.

Comment: hyperslug: Yeah, but copying and pasting a login/pass is much quicker than typing in made up info, going to mailinator to get the verification link, clicking that link, and then logging in.

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything. And even if you do, once everyone finds out about it, it will get blocked as well. So it's not even worth looking, IMO.

Comment: musicfreak: The problem is not other sites blocking bugmenot. The problem is that bugmenot themselves are preventing users from adding logins for specific sites. Therefore if there's a bugmenot clone that doesn't have this dumb policy, it would not have the same problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you meant the websites were blocking BugMeNot. Regardless, I think my comment still applies for the most part. +1

Comment: Why do you want a fake login on ubuntuforums?  If you're going to post, make an account.  If you're not going to post, you don't need an account (right?)

Comment: mailinator is awesome.  I didn't previous know of it, but anything with one of the FAQ answers being "you are a stupid-head" is pretty awesome.

Comment: Peter: Some users upload useful files, and I want to download those files without having to make an account, but the forum requires an account to download. If I wanted to post I'd make an account.

Comment: @John: What does this question have to do with paying? Are you implying I am paying less than others for some service, and yet complaining more then them? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The other great thing about BugMeNot is the Firefox extension that automatically tries to log in with a right-click, no copying and pasting necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some Bugmenot alternatives:

- **[Login 2](http://login2.me/)** - [TOS link](http://login2.me/?page=terms) - Login 2's TOS doesn't seem to have an option that allows websites to 'opt out'
- **[Password-login.com](http://password-login.com/)** - [TOS link](http://password-login.com/page/terms-and-conditions/)

I made this answer into a Community Wiki so others could easily add other Bugmenot alternatives. Please include the website's TOS, if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a service like bugmenot that doesn't block sites?

No.  There isn't.  If there was, the same power-structure that influenced bugmenot would influence it, and it would go down the same or a similar path and start blocking sites or otherwise become less useful.

Comment: come on...you're killing my hopes of finding someone willing to stand up to The Man!

Comment: "Willing to stand up to the man" is easy to find... "Still standing up after the man has had his way with them" is quite another thing.

In a semi-related vein, here's the latest back-n-forth between Google and Mozilla re: privacy: http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/asa/archives/2009/12/if_you_have_nothing.html

Comment: An alternative implementation, Firefox extension for example, could be made that used some sort of distributed model for the content. That way it would be designed to be resistant for "the man". But that opens up a whole new can of worms...

Comment: @IlariKajaste: Also, that might reduce usage of the accounts to spam, which just gets them banned?

Answer (score 2):

I hate signing up to forums just to get access to attachments, or having to register just to read a news feed. The problem is that any system that is popular enough to have good coverage is also popular enough to get sued or have all their accounts deactivated quickly. Another approach is to try common usernames/passwords like [this](http://monkeyfilter.com/link.php/5238) suggestion:

> slashdot/slashdot is always worth a
>   try - they do get just about
>   everywhere.

Comment: cypherpunk/cypherpunk (or plural) is also reasonably common.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother.  Most sites that require a registration don't do any kind of checking on the info you provide.  Use completely made-up names, addresses, phone numbers and emails, and your browser will likely remember what you've filled out one registration form with so you'll have less to type next time.  If you really need to use a site that requires email validation, give them a Yahoo or Gmail account you've created solely for that purpose, so you can hit the validation link and forget about it.

If enough people pollute these sites' registration databases with useless information, maybe the data mining companies will stop buying that data, and the sites will stop bothering to collect it.

Here's a set of Personal Information you're free to use on any site you need to register for:

```
Name:     Flubbre Golightly
Street:   987 Madeup Lane
City:     Beverly Hills, CA
Zip:      90210
Email:    notarealaddress@anywhere.com
```

Or create your own.  It's fun and easy!

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but copying and pasting a login/pass from bugmenot is much quicker than typing in made up info, going to mailinator/yahoo/gmail to get the verification link, clicking that link, and then logging in.

Comment: suit yourself.  i only do it once per site (assuming cookies are enabled) and most sites that require verifications i don't bother with.

Comment: Sure, but I'm asking for a bugmenot alternative, and your answer is "do it the way everyone did before bugmenot, and the way everyone does, now that bugmenot sucks". So while it's useful in that it provides information, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: i didn't promise a good alternative, just an alternative.  use it or don't.

Comment: -1 The whole point of bugmenot is to avoid the hassle of registering with a fake account (just to see one illustration on a forum that you're never going to use again, for instance).  Suggesting that people make their own individual fake accounts misses the point.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use an e-mail address for just that purpose, simply because bugmenot started to fail on me, just like it's happening to you.

Other than that I don't bother registering with websites that put up a registration wall If I can get the same information elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this doesn't answer my question. Perhaps there is no answer, perhaps nobody has tried creating a clone of bugmenot yet.

Answer (score -3):

There seems to be a new service called [bypass.rd.to](http://bypass.rd.to/).

They have Firefox and Chrome extensions.

From their [FAQ](http://bypass.rd.to:41/faq.php):

> How do I block my website?
>
> Sorry, we do not allow the blocking of websites from our system.

I think the amount of logins they have currently is quite limited, but maybe it will become more popular. It looks like a good BugMeNot replacement to me.

Hopefully they have established themselves somewhere with a human-friendly legal system where they can not be bothered with similar threats that made BugMeNot less useful (i.e. outside of the USA the very least).

Comment: Nice find! It seems to be regularly updated too.

Comment: I made [my answer to this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/16116/7584) into a Community Wiki, so we could have one list of all Bugmenot alternatives. If you want, you could add the above website to that. Just edit my answer.

Comment: This is a redirect to facebook?  Flagged.